# How can a file moved to a directory with GID-bit set inherit the group ownership

Tags: linux, directory, groups

### Problem

I know that a file that is created in a directory with the GID-bit set it will inherit the diretory's group ownership.
This however doesn't work for files that are moved to that directory as stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories

It happens that users move files to a shared folder instead of copying them or creating new files, there are now files in the shared folder that are not accessible to everybody.

### Example:

There is a shread folder

```
john:/home/common$ ls -l
drwxrws--- 15 john users 4096 Feb 11 09:14 shared
```

and a file in a private folder.

```
john:/home/john$ ls -l
-rw-rw---- 1 john john 512 Feb 11 09:14 test.txt
```

That file is moved to the shared folder. It keeps the group ownership.

```
john:/home/common/shared$ mv /home/john/test.txt .
john:/home/common/shared$ ls -l
-rw-rw---- 1 john john 512 Feb 11 09:14 test.txt
```

When the file is **moved** to `shared`, the group stays `john` and is not changed to `users`. If the file is **copied**, the group changed to `users`.

### My Question

Even though this behaviour is logical from a system point of view, it is not what is expected from a user point of view.

Is there a way to configure the `shared` directory so that the group is also changed automatically for files that are moved?
What is the best practice to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setgid does affect the newly created files (using `touch`, `cp`), and it does not affect the already created files (using `mv`).

There are several solutions like the [ones posted here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12842/13810). Also, you can add a cron job to periodically `chgrp` all files / folders under your shared folder.

Another possible solution is to use `incrontab -e` to fix group ownership when a file is moved to your shared folder. Be careful, this triggers events only for shared folder itself not any other subfolder.

```
/path/to/shared/dir IN_MOVED_TO /bin/chgrp users $@/$#
```